# How to add Google ads in Apk

Tags: react-native, ads, adsense, google-ads-api, google-ads-data-hub

There are some react-native components for ads but some of them don't work with current versions of react-native. (react-native-admob for example).

There is a serious lack of information about showing ads in react native and I can't seem to figure out how most people accomplish this.

Does everyone really write their own native UI component to accomplish this? Is react-native-admob really the only way to use admob currently? Am I just completely missing some simple way to do this?

[like this image](https://community.thunkable.com/uploads/default/original/3X/2/4/2408dd35f3602a8af819ab75eb04f216a395cd34.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the react-native-admob module.
Install it using npm:

```
npm install --save react-native-admob
react-native link
```

Go through their [example](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/tree/f8db0e6797efcda101e936e1bbe0c91d3f174a15/Example) for info on usage.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use react-native-firebase library and then use admob feature. Here is the complete documentation: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/admob/android